# 6U , 12U Deployer / Dispenser, helpful criteria we might use for selection?

Tags: cubesat, cost, payload-deployment

as a member of a group of students that builds 6U and 12U Cubesats for different projects I am interested in knowing the average cost of a 6U and a 12U deployer.

Also, beyond cost, what are some other major considerations or criteria we can use to compare deployers. For example, do deployers exist that can be used in several launchers or are they all launcher-specific?

Comment: no, I think they're just asking whether it's flexible enough to fit in different launchers or whether it has to be designed for a specific one

Comment: is this a [shopping list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-was-my-shopping-list-question-closed)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is written like a shopping list question.

Comment: @AJN rather than start the long, arduous close/reopen process on a new user's first question, Erin Anne just pointed out the issue to the user to help them learn about the site. Since you've now started the close process, I've gone ahead and made an edit for them to remove the "shopping question" aspects. It's hard to get started in Stack Exchange and if we can help new users without insta-closing their questions, it makes for a nicer and more welcoming experience.

Comment: @uhoh Thank you for editing the question and make it more clear. It is my first time using this platform.
We are in a very initial phase of development but already doing some analysis on available options. Is it a good approach to review the launchers manuals conditions and then compare to the available information on each deployer? Or the launchers only specify loads for primary adapters?